# Dataframe apply set is not removing duplicate values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My dataset can sometimes include duplicates in one concatenated column like this:

```
                  Total
0                 Thriller,Satire,Thriller
1                 Horror,Thriller,Horror
2                   Mystery,Horror,Mystery
3                 Adventure,Horror,Horror
```

When doind this

```
df['Total'].str.split(",").apply(set)
```

I get

```
                  Total
0                 {Thriller,Satire}
1                 {Horror,Thriller}
2                 {Mystery,Horror,Crime}
3                 {Adventure,Horror}
```

And after encoding it with

```
df['Total'].str.get_dummies(sep=",")
```

I get a header looking like this

```
{'Horror    {'Mystery   {'Thriller ... Horror Thriller'}
```

Instead of

```
Horror Mystery Thriller
```

How do I get rid of the curly brackets when using Pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) working nice also with duplicates.

So omit code for unique values:

```
df['Total'] = df['Total'].str.split(",").apply(set)
```

And use only:

```
df1 = df['Total'].str.get_dummies(sep=",")
print (df1)
   Adventure  Horror  Mystery  Satire  Thriller
0          0       0        0       1         1
1          0       1        0       0         1
2          0       1        1       0         0
3          1       1        0       0         0
```

---

BUt if need remopve duplicates add [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df1 = df['Total'].str.split(",").apply(set).str.join(',').str.get_dummies(sep=",")
```

Comment: So the first line (with only get_dummies) is just for encoding properly? I was a bit confused by how it could remove duplicates and such but then I saw the second line which seems to be doing what I needed it for.

Comment: @TheWorker - exactly, `.str.get_dummies` remove duplicates, so  `.str.split(",").apply(set).str.join(',')` not necessary here

Comment: Oh ok, so both lines are equivalent to eachother?